# unable to archive react native IOS application

Tags: ios, react-native

I'm trying to Archive an react native IOS app via Xcode but it fails with the error. The app builds ok and runs on real device and also on simulator normal only the archive fails. The error is the following:

```
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_RCTWebSocketModule in:
/Users/simoncigoj/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GoOptiDriverProject-fdekgxtfuwblpfbtjzxjseykeddi/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/GoOptiDriverProject/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/libReact.a(RCTWebSocketModule.o)
/Users/simoncigoj/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GoOptiDriverProject-fdekgxtfuwblpfbtjzxjseykeddi/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/GoOptiDriverProject/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/libRCTWebSocket.a(RCTWebSocketModule.o)
```

ld: 168 duplicate symbols for architecture arm64